# how to prevent uploading original image after it is resized

Tags: php, image, upload, resize

I am using code below to resize an image and upload the image. But as far as i can see, there are 2 images uploaded. The original one and the resized one. Only the resized one should be uploaded. I dont know how to do that.

```
$file = $_FILES['main_image']['tmp_name']; 
$sourceProperties = getimagesize($file);
$fileNewName = 'mainimage-'.time();
$folderPath = "data/uploads/";
$ext = pathinfo($_FILES['main_image']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$imageType = $sourceProperties[2];

switch ($imageType) {

    case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
        $imageResourceId = imagecreatefrompng($file); 
        $targetLayer = imageResize($imageResourceId,$sourceProperties[0],$sourceProperties[1]);
        imagepng($targetLayer,$folderPath. $fileNewName. "_resized.". $ext);
        break;

    case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
        $imageResourceId = imagecreatefromgif($file); 
        $tagetLayer = imageResize($imageResourceId,$sourceProperties[0],$sourceProperties[1]);
        imagegif($targetLayer,$folderPath. $fileNewName. "_resized.". $ext);
        break;

    case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
        $imageResourceId = imagecreatefromjpeg($file); 
        $targetLayer = imageResize($imageResourceId,$sourceProperties[0],$sourceProperties[1]);
        imagejpeg($targetLayer,$folderPath. $fileNewName. "_resized.". $ext);
        break;

    default:
        echo "Invalid Image type.";
        exit;
        break;
}
    // upload the image
    move_uploaded_file($file, $folderPath. $fileNewName. ".". $ext);
```

This is the function i use to resize:

```
// function resize image
function imageResize($imageResourceId,$width,$height) {

    $targetWidth =750;
    //$targetHeight =300;
    $targetHeight = ($height / $width) * $targetWidth; // keep ratio

    $targetLayer = imagecreatetruecolor($targetWidth,$targetHeight);
    imagecopyresampled($targetLayer,$imageResourceId,0,0,0,0,$targetWidth,$targetHeight, $width,$height);

    return $targetLayer;
}
```

Comment: There is only 1 image uploaded, the original one. You should `unlink` the original image if you don't need it: `unlink($folderPath. $fileNewName. ".". $ext); // delete original sized image` (place this after `move_uploaded_file()`)